# Powershell generates .bat, and put special character

Tags: powershell, special-characters

I'm currently working with powershell in order to create a .bat script.

I put text in .bat script with `>>`

For example,

```
Write "start program xxx" >> script.bat
```

but when i try to execute this script.bat with cmd, it says :
"■s" is not recognize ... etc.
And in powershell it says : 'þp'  is not recognize ..

So I guess that doing  `>> script`  put special character at the beginning of the line. If someone got information on this. And what those "■s" and 'þp' are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file redirection operators (`>>` etc.) will write text encoded in UTF-16. If the file already contains text in a different encoding everything will be confused (and I'm not use of `cmd.exe` understands UTF-16 at all.

Easier to use `Out-File` with the `-encoding` parameter to specify something consistent. Use the `-append` switch parameter to append rather than overwriting.

Eg.

```
"Some text" | Out-File -encoding ASCII -append -FilePath 'script.bat`
```

(If you find yourself writing the same `out-file` and parameters, then put it in a helper advanced function that will read pipeline input to encapsulate the `out-file`.)

Comment: Thank you for you perfect answer @Richard. Will try it right now, but sure it works ! Just a little question, i can put UTF-8 with -encoding, no ? It will work as well no ? thank you

Comment: Ok it works well ... Thank you very much. would have take me 1 year to realize this :)

Comment: @Nico There are lots of options for the `-encoding` parameter. See `gh out-file -param encoding` for more information.